# JQuery Timepicker Responsive Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a timepicker that works perfectly fine. However when the screen changes size e.g from a laptop to mobile, the timepicker layout changes. see image below

[image]

The code for the timepicker is here

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
 <input type='text' class="form-control" name="datetime"/>
 <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
 </span>
</div>
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which jQuery plugin are you using? There are several jQuery timepickers out there. Also, is it possible to see the CSS code associated with your issue?

Comment: The css code is coming from these links

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

Comment: fiddle is here - https://jsfiddle.net/v3srz04x/

Comment: its working fine in fiddle

Comment: please update the fiddle with your issue

Comment: it appears to be working in the fiddle but not on my site. any ideas why??

Comment: can you share me the site url or need to add css like `clear:both`